# Using value in GUIDE listbox as variable (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, listbox, matlab-guide

I am trying to build a gui to generate some plots using some information contained in the opening function. I am using a listbox to attempt to update those variables, for instance, before I even run the plot loops, I want to select an initial condition from the listbox. However, no matter what selection I make in the listbox, the initial condition always resets to 0. Here is a sort-of explanation of what I am trying to do:

Opening function:

```
x(i) = 0;
y(i) = str2double(char(get(handles.edit1, 'String');
z(i) = 0;
```

Listbox function:

```
listval = get(handles.listbox1, 'Value');

if (listval == 1)
    set(handles.edit1, 'String', '35')

elseif (listval == 2)
    set(handles.edit1, 'String', '40')

elseif (listval == 3)
    set(handles.edit1, 'String', '45')
....
```

I am certain I am calling the listbox values correctly, in that I am passing them to an edit box to display the value, and then calling the value of the edit box as the new value of y(i). However, after removing the semicolons from the assignment statements, I selected the desired value on the listbox, ran the script, but the command window showed that y = 0.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you run your script -> what is the string in `edit1` ?

Comment: It would be helpful to have a completely functional example so we can see what's happening with the rest of the GUI (see [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). How are the callbacks defined? Is this a GUIDE GUI? Programmatic?

Comment: I'll update the functions to more complete examples once I am in my office, but hopefully the following helps too. The edit box updates perfectly whenever I click on a value in the list box, however the y variable never updates to the same variable in the edit box. Is there something I need to do to force everything to update? This is a GUIDE gui.

Answer (score 0):

you are extracting from `handles.edit_box`  where as you are setting the string in `handles.edit1`

I doubt this is the same edit box...

*Note 1: This answer makes no sense now that the user has updated the question!*

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was rectified when relocating the calculations to the pushbutton functions, instead of doing it all in the opening function. This is going to make for clunkier code, but it works which is what is important!